# Separating list by decimal in Python

Tags: python

Here is my current list:

```
x = [1.0, 0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 5.4]
```

and here is what I want:

```
newx = [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```

I just need to split the list at the decimal point and do not want any extra zeros added to the new list. Seems like there should be a simple solution I just don't know about since I am so new.

Comment: are you sure all your numbers will only have one decimal place (and won't be strings that look like numbers)?

Comment: Here is the unpythonic way: `[int(c) for c in str(x) if c.isdigit()]`.

Comment: This is a list of numbers. It doesn't have any decimal points in it. Neither do the elements within it. What you're asking for is to split a list of floating-point numbers into a list of alternating integer and fractional parts… but that's a weird thing to do, because the fractional part "30" is the same as "3" under that definition. Maybe if you explain [why you want to do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) someone can give you an answer that's easier to understand—or a better way to do what you really want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = [1.0, 0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 5.4]
newx = [int(j) for i in x for j in str(i).split('.')]
>>>[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```

Btw, the comprehension works the same as this one:

```
var result = []
for i in x:
    for j in str(i).split('.'):
        result.append(int(j))
```

Comment: +1 good one, but after looking on  this and mine solution I still think that this uncomprehensible list comprehension are a bit hard to read

Comment: Perfect, simple, and works great. Can you explain to me what is happening if you get a chance?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

In a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), we take each item in the list and use [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-str) to take the number and make it into a string. We then split that string on the character `"."`:

```
(str(item).split(".") for item in x)
```

This gives us a generator of lists (`['1', '0'], ['0', '0'], ...`). We then use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten that into a single iterator:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(...)
```

Then we use a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to convert the individual digit-strings into ints again.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = [1.0, 0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 5.4]
>>> digit_strings = itertools.chain.from_iterable(str(item).split(".") for item in x)
>>> [int(item) for item in digit_strings]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```

`itertools.chain.from_iterable()` is the best tool for flattening iterables - it's efficient and flexible, and the syntax is clear (just a function call with clear documentation in the stdlib).

Comment: Please update your result to list of integers instead of list of chars.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = [1.0, 0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 5.4]
>>> y = [str(v).split(".") for v in x]  # Will give list of list

>>> [int(v) for li in y for v in li]    # Flatten the list
[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [1.0, 0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 5.4]
>>> map(int, (k for y in map(str, x) for k in y.split('.')))
[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(b) if b.isdigit() else b for a in x for b in str(a).split('.')]
```

Comment: some explanation would be nice - code only answers are not exactly useful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit cryptic but should what the OP wants:

```
>>> x = [1.0, 0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 5.4]
>>> map(int, ('.'.join(str(y) for y in x).split('.')))
[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```

It's supposed that each element in the list is a float and with one decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [1.0, 0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 5.4]
>>> a = []
>>> [a.extend(map(int, str(num).split("."))) for num in x]
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> a
[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```